# European format time - Convert string to Datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to be able to convert the following string format to Datetime.

```
'21-04-2010 11:06'
```

I've looked here but there doesn't seem to be solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
convert(datetime, '21-04-2010 11:06', ??)
```

Has anyone else come across this problem? Or is it listed somewhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
select convert(datetime, '21-04-2010 11:06', 105)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select convert(datetime, '21-04-2010 11:06', 105)
```

Here the ref http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp Basically is `dd-mm-yyyy` format

Answer (score 1):

You can use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-) date in MySQL to parse your String

Comment: sorry its not mySQL, accidentally clicked the wrong tag. Cheers anyways

Comment: no problem, have you tried 120 for your `??`? 120 is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)` format.

Comment: The op initially said that it was MySql, i dont see a reason for -1 to anybody who did it :/

Answer (score 0):

If it is sql server, use 105...like this:

```
select convert(datetime, '21-04-2010 11:06', 105)
```

it will work (sql server docs says that it is for 21-04-2010 ...but it will get your 11:06, too)